# IThemes site Lockout - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, security, plugins, lockout

I am currently using IThemes security plugin for my Wordpress/Woocommerce website.

I go on the website regularly to make sure everything is working ok. today I got locked out of the website and was unable to access any pages. I regularly get lockout emails and find out when I check the IP that it is my own IP address but luckily I am logged in as administrator at the time so do not get locked out.

My main concern is that I do not access invalid URL's / 404's. yet the plug in is deeming, somehow, that I am....

Is there anyway, anyone knows of that I can check to see f maybe a plug in is conflicting?

Any help would be great as I am scared that when my website is running properly that potential customers may get locked out which will not be good for business

Answer (score 0):

The quickest, and safest way to conduct a check to see if any plugin (or combination of plugins) is causing an issue with your WordPress install is by doing the following:

1. Log into the respective website via FTP.
2. Head over to the plugin folder, which is located at /yourWebsite/wp-content/plugins
3. If you have any security plugins, I would start by re-naming one of the plugin folders, by adding another letter to the folder name.
4. Refresh your website and see if the issue has been fixed, if the issue hasn't been fixed yet, be sure to re-name the folder **BACK** to it's **ORIGINAL** name.
5. Rinse & repeat, eventually if a plugin is causing the problem - it will be fixed as the plugin gets disabled by renaming the folder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. my main concern with this approach is that, the lockout notifications are quite sporadic. I can go a few days with none and then get 60 in one day, which would mean I would potentially need to disable a plugin for a number of days before getting any sort of indication and with all the active plugins it would potentially take months to figure out :-( lol

Comment: I see, well I mean perhaps at this point you can only really assume that it probably is likely that the security plugin is causing the lock-out. For general security plugins, I personally tend to use WordFence. It works miracles, and it is updated very frequently. That would be the first thing I would do is switch the security plugin if the lockouts are that sporadic.